# What is the correct syntax for PHP/SQL prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently created a PHP/SQL prepared statement where only one variable is being passed through. However it is failing to prepare. My guess is that it is probably due to syntax. What have I done wrong?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (noteText) VALUES ?";
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO notes(noteText) VALUES(?)"` then it depends what extension you use (mysqli vs pdo vs ...), how you do your binds and execute your query => consider providing your whole code for further help

Comment: See https://phpdelusions.net

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (noteText) VALUES (?)";
```

I placed the `?` for `VALUES` in brackets that's how it should be.

For more information take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

A full example using a few different methods:

```
// MySQLi
$conn; // connection variable
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO notes (noteText) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $noteText);

$noteText = "Lorem Ipsum....";
$stmt->execute();

// PDO with Named Parameters
$db; // Database Handler
$sql  ="INSERT INTO notes (noteText) VALUES (:noteText)";
$noteText = "Lorem Ipsum....";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':noteText', $noteText, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

Personal preference with the named parameters. Just easier for me to keep up with them :)